# A timed switch with Dynamic

Tags: dynamic

I'm trying to make a binary switch that switches after a fixed given interval. Why doesn't the following work:

```
step = .1;
t = Dynamic[Clock[{0, 5, step}, 5, 1] ]; 
Dynamic[t >=  2]
```

Comment: Could someone with at least 300 points of reputation please add some more tags?

Comment: `Dynamic[Clock[] > .5]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that you've defined `t` as a `Dynamic` expression. A relational operator like `GreaterEqual` (`>=`) works with numeric expressions like the result of `Clock`. You could try something like this to get a displayed output that eventually switches from `False` to `True`:

```
step = .1;
Dynamic[{t, t = Clock[{0., 5., step}, 5., 1]; t >= 2}]
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't help thinking about this question even after I voted for billsphere's perfectly satisfactory answer. Finally, I concluded that `Trigger` would be a better way to implement the requested functionality. It is just as easy to use as `Clock` and throws in a nice little control panel as a bonus.

```
With[{dt = 1, tmax = 10, threshold = 4}, 
  Column[{
    Dynamic @ Row[{t, " > ", threshold, " is ", t > threshold}],
    Trigger[Dynamic @ t, {0, tmax, dt}, dt]}]]
```

[image: trigger]

Comment: @ m_goldberg, nope, Trigger doesn't work on the Linux version :-(